# reading JSON file sometimes working and sometimes not working (Python)

Tags: python, json

Here's the top bit of the code that's relevant:

```
url1 = "https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/new/.json"
response = urllib.urlopen(url1)
data = json.loads(response.read())
tiloriginal = []

    for post in data["data"]["children"]:
        tilfact = post["data"]["title"]
```

So the weird thing is, my code works fine. But I'd like like 2/5 of the time, it gives me the following error:

```
    for post in data["data"]["children"]:
KeyError: 'data'
```

When I run the script again though, it works fine. But then when I run it again, it would give me the error again.

It's the exact same code being run every single time, but only **sometimes** does it give me this error.

Any help on why this is the case??? Is it something wrong with my code? My internet?

Comment: Maybe the moment you query the server, the one the server that took your response got some error, first check if its a 200 ok and then check if data exists in the dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always check the response code first.

```
In [44]: url1 = "https://www.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/new/.json"

In [45]: requests
Out[45]: <module 'requests' from '.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/__init__.py'>

In [46]: requests.get(url1)
Out[46]: <Response [429]>

In [47]: requests.get(url1)
Out[47]: <Response [200]>

In [48]: requests.get(url1)
Out[48]: <Response [200]>

In [49]: requests.get(url1)
Out[49]: <Response [429]>

In [50]:
```

Here, you can see there are some 200's (success) and some 429's (Too Many Requests).

if you use the requests 3rd party lib, this is easy:

```
In [52]: r=requests.get(url1)

In [53]: r
Out[53]: <Response [429]>

In [54]: r.status_code
Out[54]: 429
```

So what you would do then is a while loop that checks (say) 3 or 5 times?

like:

```
r = requests.get(url1)
status_count = 0
while r.status_code == 429 and status_count < 3:
    r = requests.get(url1)
    status_count += 1
```

for example

(i'm only checking for 429 - too many requests in this case, because i wouldn't want to mask other codes, like 404, or 500, etc)

Oh, and one more thing - given that these are 429's - it might be smart to put an `import time; time.sleep(1)` type thing at the beginning of that while statement.

Comment: Could you explain what the In[46]Out[46] things are please? I'm new to this :(. Did you write that into your code?

Comment: No, that's output from the terminal. I use an ipython terminal - which is super handy. It has things like tab complete and other nifty functions that make life as a developer easier. You can install ipython by doing pip install ipython (if you have pip installed). If you aren't sure what pip is, just ask.